# Remove index column while saving csv in pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm trying to create a `csv` with pandas, but when I export the data to `csv` it gives me an extra column

```py
d = {'one' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3.]),'two' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3., 4.])}
df0_fa = pd.DataFrame(d)
df_csv = df0_fa.to_csv('revenue/data/test.csv',mode = 'w')
```

Thus, my result is:

```
 ,one,two
0,1.0,1.0
1,2.0,2.0
2,3.0,3.0
3,4.0,4.0
```

But, the expected results are:

```
one,two
1.0,1.0
2.0,2.0
3.0,3.0
4.0,4.0
```

Answer (score 149, accepted):

What you are seeing is the index column. Just set `index=False`:

```
df_csv = df0_fa.to_csv('revenue/data/test.csv',mode = 'w', index=False)
```

Comment: I don't know how I missed this in the documentation, but great catch! That was frustrating me forever, trying to figure out where I added the index as a column.

Comment: I banged my head against that more than I should have as well.

Comment: And in case anyone is also trying to remove the column names, you can pass in `header=False`.

Answer (score 13):

To read the csv file without indexing you can unset the index_col to prevent pandas from using your first column as an index. And while saving the csv back onto the disk, do not forget to **set index = false** in `to_csv`. This will not generate an additional index column. Else, if you need to delete/remove a specific column from the data frame, use `drop` , it worked for me as follows :

```
import pandas as pd
file_path = 'example_file.csv'
data_frame = pd.read_csv(file_path, index_col = False)
column_name = 'column'
data_frame = data_frame.drop(column_name, axis = 1) 
data_frame.to_csv(file_path, index = False)
```

In this case, even if your csv has a valid index column, you can skip `index_col = False` in `read_csv`.