# Pandas read_csv incorrectly reading headers

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading a csv file using 'pd.read_csv' and writing it to another csv using 'file.to_csv'. It is incorrectly displaying the headers in the output file. For example,

**input**:

```
ABC | 20151004 | 1900 | 0000000002 | MUPPETS SP 1-10/4, THE |  |  | R|RS

0

0

0

0

0

2993
```

**script**:

```
data = pd.read_csv(r'filepath/input.csv')
```

print data

**Input header**: `ABC | 20151004 | 1900 | 0000000002 | MUPPETS SP 1-10/4, THE |  |  | R|RS`

**Output header**: `ABC | 20151004 | 1900 | 0000000002 | MUPPETS SP 1-10/4, THE |  |  | R|RS.1`

Not sure why it is adding `'.1'` to the end of some of the headers.

Comment: add first five lines from csv file here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20845213/how-to-avoid-python-pandas-creating-an-index-in-a-saved-csv

Comment: Better duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26786960/pandas-to-csv-first-extra-column-remove-how-to

Comment: I tried using index=False param. I am receiving below error.

TypeError: parser_f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'index'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data = pd.read_csv(r'filepath/input.csv',sep='|')
```

The rs.1 is likely indicative of duplicate 'rs' columns

Comment: Thank you. You are right. It's a large file and I did not notice it.It is a duplicate column. Is there a way to read the column as it is without adding '.1' in the end?

Comment: you need to add some columns to the question, to solve.  Those dont look like headers but rather its all data.  You also need to  work through a tutorial before posting questions.  https://people.duke.edu/~ccc14/sta-663/IntroductionToPythonSolutions.html