# Pandas adding blank column title with a count

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am working on manipulating some csv's for my job. The code below works, it just has one minor issue. It is adding a column in front of the line "`df.insert(0,'ID',' ')`" with a blank column name and it is counting the number of rows. Is there any reason as to why this is happening? Please feel free to offer any insight or pick apart what I have as I am new to Python and I am sure this can be cleaned up or run more efficiently.

Thanks,

```
import pandas as pd

# Enter the full file path you want manipulated here
print('Enter Filename Path')
file = input()

# Enter the report category you want added here. This needs to be exact
print('Report Category')
rcat = input()

# Reads the CSV given above
df = pd.read_csv(file)

# This inserts the columns needed to fit the new VulnMan DB
df.insert(0, 'ID', ' ')
df.insert(4, 'Report Category', (rcat))
df.insert(5, 'Status', 'Not Started ')
df.insert(6, 'Comments', ' ')

# Saves the file in the SAME NAME
df.to_csv(file)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas to\_csv first extra column remove, how to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26786960/pandas-to-csv-first-extra-column-remove-how-to)

Comment: This looks like a duplicate thanks for the heads up and sorry for a duplicate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the index of the `DataFrame`. You can get rid of it in the exported file using

```
df.to_csv(file, index=False)
```

Comment: This is perfect thank you. One other question. In the file variable is there a way to have it always know the location and I just provide it the file name? For instance these files will always be here "C:\Users\NAME\Downloads". Can I add something to the above code to have it know that location and I just provide it with "cvsname.csv"?

Comment: You could let `folder = 'C:\\Users\\NAME\Downloads\\'` somewhere and use `folder + file` where relevant.

Comment: This worked as well. Thanks for the help, sorry for the long delay in reaching back out.