# Python Pandas replacing part of a string

Tags: python, string, pandas, replace

I'm trying to filter data that is stored in a .csv file that contains time and angle values and save filtered data in an output .csv file. I solved the filtering part, but the problem is that time is recorded in hh:mm:ss:msmsmsms (12:55:34:500) format and I want to change that to hhmmss (125534) or in other words remove the : and the millisecond part.
I tried using the .replace function but I keep getting the KeyError: 'time' error.

Input data:

```
time,angle
12:45:55,56
12:45:56,89
12:45:57,112
12:45:58,189
12:45:59,122
12:46:00,123
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

#define min and max angle values
alpha_min = 110
alpha_max = 125

#read input .csv file
data = pd.read_csv('test_csv3.csv', index_col=0)

#filter by angle size
data = data[(data['angle'] < alpha_max) & (data['angle'] > alpha_min)]

#replace ":" with "" in time values
data['time'] = data['time'].replace(':','')

#display results
print data

#write results
data.to_csv('test_csv3_output.csv')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `time` is an index. You can do this and remove the `index_col=0`:

```
data = pd.read_csv('test_csv3.csv')
```

And change this line:

```
data['time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['time']).dt.strftime('%H%M%S')
```

**Output:**

```
     time  angle
2  124557    112
4  124559    122
5  124600    123
```

Comment: the {index_col=0} was used to remove the extra first column that appears in the results (it also appears in your answer). I tried your code correction and still get the same error. Perhaps I should add I'm using python2.7 because of some compatibility issues with openCV.

Comment: Correction: your code works (almost - now I need to find a way to remove the added column in the output). I checked the print (data.keys()) as per Daniel B's answer and found out I had a mistake in the input file, which I did not recognize before. I was using the Notepad++ to check the .csv files which was not showing me the last version of the file, which is very strange.

Comment: found the answer, data.to_csv('test_csv3_output.csv',index=False) from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26786960/remove-index-column-while-saving-csv-in-pandas

Answer (score 1):

What would `print (data.keys())` or `print(data.head())` yield? It seems like you have a stray character before\after the **time** index string, happens from time to time, depending on how the csv was created vs how it was read (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35831496/key-error-when-selecting-columns-in-pandas-dataframe-after-read-csv)).

If it's not a bigger project and/or you just want the data, you could just do some silly workaround like: `timeKeyString=list(data.columns.values)[0]` (assuming time is the first one).

Comment: I checked print (data.keys()) or print(data.head()) and the tips from the answer you linked and I don't have any stray characters. The code from NYC Coder works for me, but now I need to find a way to remove the added 0 column in the output file.

Comment: dataframes can't exist without the index column. You can, however, pass an argument for the export function to drop it in the output file: `print(data.to_csv(sep='\t', index=False))`